# parse unable to send push notifications , pushes sent is 0

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

I am new to parse...I am working on push notification (android) . I am running it with out any errors but could'nt send a notification to a device. Its showing that "this will be sent to 2 devices"..but pushes sent is always 0. please help me regarding this... !

Comment: Did you figure anything out ever?

Answer (score 0):

This might be slightly old, but I just faced this and the issue is with the project setting

```
In Settings->Push-> Client Push Enabled -> Toggle to Yes
```